# Change the default Dock stack content display style

Tags: dock, defaults

I love the Dock stacks. But I always use the list view option. I don't really fancy the default "Automatic" option. Do you know if it is possible (maybe using the `defaults` command?) to set the default way to display the content of a Dock stack?

Thanks in advance for your help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would change the style of all stacks to list, but you have to relaunch Dock to apply the changes:

`for n in {0..19}; do /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set persistent-others:$n:tile-data:showas 3" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Dock.plist; done 2> /dev/null`

You could run it every 8 hours by running `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and adding a line like `0 */8 * * * for n in ...`.

Comment: User mark steward says this solution "knocks out ability in Safari to view local image files in local edited HTML"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a option like this. But you can always right click on your stack and select a fixed way to show that specific stack.

Although, maybe you can find this option using this: [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com). This is a app that gives you a lot of hidden options.